# How to replace element on a model data base on django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to replace the "content" data in the database, but I don't know how, I am new to Django.

For now, it adds a new item to my database, but I just want to modify an item that is already in my database.

models.py

```
class number(models.Model):
    item = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item
```

views.py

```
def promo(request):
    form = numberform()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = numberform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            numberclean = form.cleaned_data["num"]
            print(numberclean)
            test = number(item="numberall", content=numberclean)
            test.save()
        else:
            form = numberform()

            return render(request, "promo/home.html", {"form": form})
    return render(request, "promo/home.html", {"form": form})
```

forms.py

```
class numberform(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = number
        fields = ["num"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be asking for [update_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#specifying-which-fields-to-save). Here is a simple example:

```
# Say, id is collected from url parameter
test = number.objects.get(id=id)
test.content="Your content"
test.save(update_fields=['content'])
```

Answer (score 0):

to update a model use this command:

```
 number.objects.filter(item__exact="numberall").update(content=numberclean )
```